# Website Asp.NET changing IIS parameters on launch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a Website Asp.NET project, and each time I load the solution in visual studio, IIS parameters of the IIS corresponding website are modified (the physical path especially).

How can I avoid that ?

I even want it not to modify the parameters on launching (when I run the solution) if possible.

Comment: What IIS parameters are you talking about? Can you give an example? Do you mean the port number in the site's URL?

Comment: Asp.net uses an IIS website to be served. This website has parameters, like its name, its application pool and especially the physical path (IIS Manager -> MyWebsite -> Base Parameters -> Physical Path). The problem is, if i put a custom path here and then load my solution in visual studio, the path parameter is modified and points to the location of my asp.net project.

Comment: The Asp.net project and the IIS website are linked, and i want to break this link.

Comment: also, What visual studio version are you using?
it's misleading to reference to the solution causing this behavior.. it's likely the 'Website' project item there, and it's likely your answer will be in the scope of project properties

Comment: I use Visual Studio Community 2017. "it's misleading to reference to the solution" what do you mean ? My solution seems to be loaded well.

Comment: For your "Start Options" in your 'Property Page' of your Website, are you using 'Default Web Server', or 'Custom Server'?

Comment: I only have two options "IIS local" and "External Host". I chose "IIS local".

Comment: hmm.. that is another matter.. a `Website` project and `Web Application` project are different project types and it seems like your project isn't a 'Website' it's an Application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149854/discussion-between-brett-caswell-and-fazega).

Comment: That's what happens when visual studio does when you open solution with web application in it. If web app is configure to one of the site on local IIS , visual studio will make sure that the site points to web app directory for the developer to be able to debug. The solution for this would be to have two different sites pointing to different directories.